# ImportError:No module named 'pydot'

Tags: python

I have used anaconda to install graphviz and pydot. The strange thing is that I can import pydot in terminal, but I can not import pydot in jupyter notebook. It confuses me for a long time. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRcN6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbIek.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Paste the error message and then properly format it.

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter says it runs at anaconda env
but, at terminal ,it runs at python env ,you should try `pip install pydot`